# Update one select on the basis of another select

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, symfony

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to load second dropdown list from database after first dropdown list is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566114/how-to-load-second-dropdown-list-from-database-after-first-dropdown-list-is-chan)

Hey I have a form with two select dropdowns in it.

The first select is populated with the portfolios of a user and the 2nd one needs to be populated with the portfolio groups. I get all the portfolios of the logged in user and populate the 1st select with those portfolios now I want to populate the 2nd select with the groups on the basis of 1st select, For-example if user select portfolio_1 all the groups in the portfolio_1 should be loaded in the 2nd select box.

The 1st select with portfolios is:

```
<select id="portfolios" name="portfolio" style="width: 200px; height:25px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="default">Select Portfolio</option>
    {% for portfolio in portfolios %}
        <option value={{ portfolio.id }}>{{ portfolio.portfolioName }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

What I understand is I need to call an ajax function onchange of the 1st select in that ajax I need to send the selected portfolio id and find all the groups with that id and then return all those groups and update only the 2nd select box with those groups,

I dont know how can I populate the 2nd select with the groups I will get

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="portfolios" name="portfolio" style="width: 200px; height:25px;" onchange="getgropus(this.value)">
<option selected="selected" value="default">Select Portfolio</option>
{% for portfolio in portfolios %}
    <option value={{ portfolio.id }}>{{ portfolio.portfolioName }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<select id="secondselectBox" name="secondselectBox"  ></select>

call the ajax function on the onchange event of your 1st selectbox
// here is JS code

<script type="text/javascript">
function getgropus(id){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "your php file path to get groups ",
            data: "&id="+id,
            complete: function(data) {
                $('#secondselectBox').html(data.responseText)
            }
        });
}

</script>

on your php file make options for selectbox of group portfolio and adjust according to your requirnments

<option value="default">Portfolio groups</option>
 .......
```

Comment: Cannot I return the portfolio groups from my ajax call and put it in the option of the 2nd select in my view?

Comment: you have to call ajax on  your 1st selectbox onchange event
after that the id of groups you will get in the getgropus(id) now this id goes to your php file which you will mention in the url part of your ajax function and on php file jst make options tag according to "id" (value of 1st selectbox) and after this echo all options , which will added in the html of 2nd selectbox

Answer (score 0):

Well i would just return them in JSON format and then inject them into the DOM:

```
$('#portfolios').on('change', function(){
   $.getJSON('url/for/groups', function(pgroups) {
       var html = '';

       $.each(pgroups, function(value, name) {
           html += '<option value="'+value+'">'+name+'</option>';
       });

       $('#portfolio-groups').html(html);
   });
});
```

Comment: How can I return them from my ajax call as JSON?

Comment: Just build an array in php as `id => key` and then return the json string by using `json_encode($theArray)`. Youll need to make sure you set your headers appropriately in the controller and what not.