# Best way to make a Symfony2 Form with multi select in cascade

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have 3 entity (Country, Region, City)

```
namespace ****\****Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Country
{
  private $id;

  private $name;

  /**
   * @var integer $regions
   * 
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Region", mappedBy="Country")
   */
  protected $regions;
  //...
}

class Region
{
  private $id;

  private $name;

  /**
   * @var integer $country
   *
   * @Assert\Type(type="****\***Bundle\Entity\Country")
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="regions")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
   */
  private $country;

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="City", mappedBy="Region")
   */
  protected $cities;
}

class City
{
    private $id;

    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer $region
     *
     * @Assert\Type(type="****\****Bundle\Entity\Region")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Region", inversedBy="cities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $region;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Company", mappedBy="City")
     */
    protected $companys;
//...
}
```

Here is my Form Class for City:

```
namespace ****\****Bundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CityType extends AbstractType
{

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('region');
  }

  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => '****\****Bundle\Entity\City',
    ));
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'city';
  }
}
```

This make a basic HTML5 Form with a textBox for the name and a SelectBox where all the region is available.

My question is what is the best way for adding a first SelectBox that will allow me to select the country in order to filter the second SelectBox and decrease the number of choice of Region?

EventListener ?
The Event Dispatcher Component ?

Answer (score 2):

NO, EventListener and Event dispatcher are for events that happen ON THE SERVER, not on the client side. You need to use Javascript. When one of the select boxes changes, this should fire a javascript function and either make an AJAX call and fill the other select box with the results of that call or use some javascript code to select which options to show on the second box.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054814/update-one-select-on-the-basis-of-another-select) for some ideas

Answer (score 1):

As Carlos Granados said you have basically two options:

1. Create a separate Symfony actions that takes a country as parameter and returns a list of associated regions in XML or JSON format. (You can use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse`to send a JSON response, however, there is no corresponding `XmlResponse` class). Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (or any other JS library or even plain Javascript) to send a request to the server whenever a user changes the currently selected item. In the callback (when you retrieved the response in the Javascript) you can update the region select box. You may find the documentation of [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) interesting.
2. You store a list of all countries and its associated regions in your HTML code (you can use JSON or generate a native Javascript array) and whenever a user changes the value of the country select box you just have to replace the list of regions in the regions select box.

The second method has a heavier load on the initial loading of the form since all countries and its associated regions must be loaded (from the database or a text file or wherever you store them) and rendered in a format that can be easily read by JS.

The first method however must send a request every time a user selects another country. Additionally you have to implement another action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this myself on a form.
I change a field (a product) and the units in which the quantity can be measured are updated.
I am using a macro with parameters to adapt it more easily.

The macro :

```
{% macro javascript_filter_unit(event, selector) %}
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#usersection')
                .on('{{ event }}', '{{ selector }}', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (!$(this).val()) return;
                    $.ajax({
                        $parent: $(this).closest('.child_collection'),
                        url: $(this).attr('data-url'),
                        type: "get",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {'id' : $(this).val(), 'repo': $(this).attr('data-repo'), parameter: $(this).attr('data-parameter')},
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result['success'])
                            {
                                var units = result['units'];
                                this.$parent.find('.unit').eq(0).html(units);   
                            }
                        }
                    });
                })
    });

</script>

{% endmacro %}
```

The ajax returns an array : array('success' => $value, 'units' => $html). You use the $html code and put it in place of the select you want to change.
Of course the javascript code of the ajax call need to be modfied to match your fields.

You call the macro like you would normally do:

```
{% import ':Model/Macros:_macros.html.twig' as macros %}
{{ macros.javascript_filter_unit('change', '.unitTrigger') }}
```

So I have two arguments : the event, often a change of a select. and a selector, the one whose change triggers the ajax call.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Carlos Granados said, you have to use client-side programming:Javascript.
I run also into the same problem as yours and came out with a solution that worked perfectly for me, here is [the snippet on codepen](https://codepen.io/medunes/pen/GWoojz), you can get inspired from (Cascade Ajax Selects)

```
    //-------------------------------SELECT CASCADING-------------------------//
    var currentCities=[];
// This is a demo API key that can only be used for a short period of time, and will be unavailable soon. You should rather request your API key (free)  from http://battuta.medunes.net/   
var BATTUTA_KEY="00000000000000000000000000000000"
    // Populate country select box from battuta API
    url="http://battuta.medunes.net/api/country/all/?key="+BATTUTA_KEY+"&callback=?";
    $.getJSON(url,function(countries)
    {
        console.log(countries);
      $('#country').material_select();
        //loop through countries..
        $.each(countries,function(key,country)
        {
            $("<option></option>")
                            .attr("value",country.code)
                            .append(country.name)
                            .appendTo($("#country"));

        }); 
        // trigger "change" to fire the #state section update process
        $("#country").material_select('update');
        $("#country").trigger("change");


    });

    $("#country").on("change",function()
    {

        countryCode=$("#country").val();

        // Populate country select box from battuta API
        url="http://battuta.medunes.net/api/region/"
        +countryCode
        +"/all/?key="+BATTUTA_KEY+"&callback=?";

        $.getJSON(url,function(regions)
        {
            $("#region option").remove();
            //loop through regions..
            $.each(regions,function(key,region)
            {
                $("<option></option>")
                                .attr("value",region.region)
                                .append(region.region)
                                .appendTo($("#region"));
            });
            // trigger "change" to fire the #state section update process
            $("#region").material_select('update');
            $("#region").trigger("change");

        }); 

    });
    $("#region").on("change",function()
    {

        // Populate country select box from battuta API
        countryCode=$("#country").val();
        region=$("#region").val();
        url="http://battuta.medunes.net/api/city/"
        +countryCode
        +"/search/?region="
        +region
        +"&key="
        +BATTUTA_KEY
        +"&callback=?";

        $.getJSON(url,function(cities)
        {
            currentCities=cities;
            var i=0;
            $("#city option").remove();

            //loop through regions..
            $.each(cities,function(key,city)
            {
                $("<option></option>")
                                .attr("value",i++)
                                .append(city.city)
                        .appendTo($("#city"));
            });
            // trigger "change" to fire the #state section update process
            $("#city").material_select('update');
            $("#city").trigger("change");

        }); 

    }); 
    $("#city").on("change",function()
    {
      currentIndex=$("#city").val();
      currentCity=currentCities[currentIndex];
      city=currentCity.city;
      region=currentCity.region;
      country=currentCity.country;
      lat=currentCity.latitude;
      lng=currentCity.longitude;
      $("#location").html('<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <strong> '+city+"/"+region+"</strong>("+lat+","+lng+")");
    });
   //-------------------------------END OF SELECT CASCADING-------------------------//
```